# Exercise 1.1 in Teschl's ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am writing this post primarily to check and verify my reasoning. During my undergrad, I took a purely computational ODEs course, and now am reading through Teschl's in an attempt to understand them deeper. I wanted to confirm my reasoning in problem 1.1, as I feel like it will be the easiest in a painful road of self study.

Problem 1.1 asks the following: *Consider the case of a stone dropped form the height h. Denote by r the distance of the stone from the surface. The initial condition reads $r(0)=h, \dot{r}(0)=0$. The equation of motion reads*

$$ \ddot{r} = -\frac{\gamma M}{(R+r)^2}$$ (exact model)
$$ \ddot{r} = -g $$
(approximate model)

where $-g$ is just the original content without $r$ in the $(R+r)^2$ term.

The issues I am having is first: Is my reasoning correct for **(ii)** and **(iii)**, as I found the others not so difficult.

**(ii)** Compute the solution for the approximate system given the initial condition. Compute the time it takes for the stone to hit the surface ($r=0$)

My solution is as follows:

As we know that $$\dot{v}(t) = -g$$
is independent of $v$, we integrate with respect to $t$ to get
$$v(t) = -g \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}t + C_1$$

I believe we make this a vector, as it is assumed that $(0,0,-1)$ is a force pulling an object 'down' in the $z$ direction and $v$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$? Then, integrating this we learn that...

$$r(t) = -\frac{g}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}t^{2} + C_1 t + C_2 $$

where $C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb{R^3}$. We apply the initial conditions to see that $C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = h$, and thus

$$r(t) = \frac{-g}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}t^{2} + h $$

where $h = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ h \end{pmatrix} $. I then just solved to get $t = \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$

Question **(iii)** essentially just asks: Is this an over or under approximation? By how much? Estimate the difference.

If I can confirm this thought, I know computation of the difference will be easy. My thinking is that the actual model is bounded as follows...

$$ -g \leq \ddot{r} \leq - \frac{\gamma M}{(R+h)^2}  $$

as $-g$ does not include the $r$ term and $h$ is the maximum height the stone achieves.

Comment: You do not need to use 3D vectors as the whole motion is considered to be only in radial direction. One could argue that where the approximation becomes insufficient the Earth rotation needs to be taken into account... but that's not intended here.

Comment: I was really confused that the problem was using 3D position, then realized it was taking $r,\dot{r},$ and $\ddot{r}$ as functions $ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and noticed the example used it. Is it generally a good rule to only use numbers if the movement is restricted along 1 axis (in this case, up & down?)

Answer (score 1):

One usual trick for conservative force fields is to multiply with $2\dot r$ and integrate once, to get
$$
\dot r^2=\frac{γM}{R+r}-\frac{γM}{R+h}=\frac{γM(h-r)}{(R+r)(R+h)}
$$
Approximations or inequalities based on this might be somewhat sharper than the ones by your approach.

Comment: I love the suggestion, two questions -- where does the conservative nature of the force field get used in justifying the use of $\dot{r}^2$ for approximations? Where does this break with nonconservative force fields? Also, are we multiplying by $2\dot{r}$ or $2\ddot{r}$ given that $r$ was our position function?

Comment: Consevative force fields are gradient fields, $m\ddot x=-\nabla V(x)$. These can always be integrated to the energy functional $E=\frac{m}2|\dot x|^2+V(x)$. Other terms like friction are not integrable under this approach, they lead to energy dissipation.